# How to access current user's attributes from search view filters in odoo?

Tags: odoo

I have a entity "request" that has a Many2one "department_id" attribute (hr.department). I have also extended the res.users models to have a reference of the department of that user (department_id)
I want to create a filter in the search view to get all requests of the department of the current user. I've tried with this code but when i clic the filter it shows "Error: AttributeError: object has no attribute 'department_id'"

Search view of the request entity:

```
<filter name="my_department" string="From my department" domain="[('department_id','=', uid.department_id)]"/>
```

Extending res.users:

```
 class User(models.Model):
        _inherit = ['res.users']

        department_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='hr.department',
                                         compute="_compute_departament",
                                         string="Departament")
    @api.multi
    @api.depends('employee_ids')
    def _compute_departament(self):
        for record in self:
            if record.employee_ids and record.employee_ids[0].department_id:
                record.departament_id = record.employee_ids[0].department_id
```

Comment: `uid` is the current user id, you can't get current user field values using dot notation.

Comment: What should I do to get current user field values in the search view?